# How to combine estUD's into single layer

Tags: r

I have some data for 10 animals from which I have generated some random points. Each data set I have replicated 100 times. Below I have separated out of the data 1 animal and generated kernelUD's for each rep. I would now like someway to combine the UD's to be able to produce a summed estimated density map which I can then go on and measure 50% and 90% home ranges along with other metrics.

```
bat.master <- read.csv("C:/Users/Sim/Dropbox/Wallington GIS/bat.master")

names(bat.master)

# subset data frame to 1st bat only
bat1 <- bat.master$id="Y2889a"

xybat1 <- subset(bat.master, bat.master$id == "Y2889a",select=x:loopno )

# change to spatial points
xy <- xybat1[1:2]  # first two rows save as coords
SPDF <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords=xy, data=df)  # combine df and xy


ud1 <- kernelUD(SPDF, h = "href", same4all = TRUE, kern = "bivnorm")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your question right, but you could try something like this:

```
library(adehabitatHR)

## generate some dummy data
SPDF <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords=cbind(rnorm(1000), rnorm(1000)),
                               data=data.frame(id=rep(1:10, each=100)))

udHR <- kernelUD(SPDF, h = "href", same4all = TRUE, kern = "bivnorm") 


## I would proceed using the raster packages
library(raster)
ud1 <- stack(lapply(udHR, raster))

## You can now check the first one
plot(ud1[[1]])

## or at all of them
plot(ud1)

## take the mean
plot(udm <- mean(ud1))

## now you can either proceed in raster and calculate your isopleths or convert it back to a estUD, this is a bit of a hack and not the nicest way to do it
udHR <- udHR[[1]]
udHR@grid <- as(udm, "GridTopology")

## now you can work with udHR as if it were a HR estimate
plot(getverticeshr(udHR, percent=95))
plot(getverticeshr(udHR, percent=50), add=TRUE)
```